# Why does VPS with stock Debian contain cdrom device?

Tags: debian, system-installation, devices, vps

I recently set up a debian 12 VPS with a new hosting company. It has:

```
/media/cdrom -> cdrom0/
/media/cdrom0/
```

And in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

Debian VPSs in my old hosting company do not have that. The new hosting company is well-known and reputable, but I was surprised as it assures customers only plain debian images are used, without modification.

Why would the cdrom device be installed for a VPS? I want to remove it; could it be required for something like a recovery process?

(Or maybe my old hoster disables cdrom, and the new hoster correctly provisions stock debian?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to tell without knowing your hoster's setup more closely. But the obvious reasons I'd see are:

1. The CDROM mount entry is a leftover from the debian provisioning process (and could have been removed,  which your old hoster did correctly)
2. The entry is for when you mount a disk image through your hoster's management interface, e.g. to install additional drivers, guest OS extensions etc.

Regarding recovery processes: it's a VM; you'd just roll back an older image of the storage.